# If set $C$ has 60 elements, and set $B_i$ has 9 elements randomly sampled from $C$, what is the mean value of $i$ to seeing all elements of $C$?

Tags: probability, statistics

This question is inspired by the Yu-Gi-Oh TCG. Every so often, the game receives a new **set** containing either 60 or 100 new cards (this is the set $C$ in the question title). However, they don't just sell you the 60 or 100 cards upfront. No, instead you must buy *booster packs*, each of which contains 9 cards randomly sampled from the 60 or 100 cards of the entire set (this is the set $B_i$ in the question title).

With the question's inspiration out of the way, my question is this: On average, how many booster packs are required to collect the entire 60 or 100-card set? A related question would be: What is the probability of having the entire set after opening $x$ booster packs?

Comment: This problem has a name: the [Coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector's_problem).  Assuming you can have duplicate cards in the same pack, you can see every pack of cards as just 9 consecutive 1 card packs. Therefore, you need to divide the expected number of attempts for 1 card packs by 9 to get the expected number of booster packs.